# Count number of non-zero columns for each row

Tags: r

For my example data frame below I would like for each row to count the number of columns that is not zero. I have tried with the `mutate` function.

```
df <- 
structure(list(Patient1 = c("0", "0", "1.5"), Patient2 = c("1", 
"0", "0"), Patient3 = c("2", "4", "1")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Gene1", 
"Gene2", "Gene3"))
```

df

```
      Patient1 Patient2 Patient3
Gene1        0        1        2
Gene2        0        0        4
Gene3      1.5        0        1
```

Out:

```
      Patient1 Patient2 Patient3 Zero NonZero
Gene1        0        1        2 1    2
Gene2        0        0        4 2    1
Gene3      1.5        0        1 1    2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(
    Zero = sum(c_across(starts_with("Patient"))==0),
    NonZero = sum(c_across(starts_with("Patient"))!=0)
  )

# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Rowwise: 
  Patient1 Patient2 Patient3  Zero NonZero
  <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <int>   <int>
1 0        1        2            1       2
2 0        0        4            2       1
3 1.5      0        1            1       2
```

Comment: Nice solution. Actually, not all columns starts with "Patients" for my real data.

Comment: You can insert other columns inside c_across, and with others functions

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `rowSums()` function which is quite efficient

```
# dplyr solution
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(zero      = rowSums(. == 0),
         non_zero  = rowSums(. != 0))
#>       Patient1 Patient2 Patient3  zero non_zero
#> Gene1        0        1        2     1        2
#> Gene2        0        0        4     2        1
#> Gene3      1.5        0        1     1        2

# base solution
df$zero     <- rowSums(df == 0)
df$non_zero <- rowSums(df != 0)
df
#>       Patient1 Patient2 Patient3 zero non_zero
#> Gene1        0        1        2    1        3
#> Gene2        0        0        4    2        2
#> Gene3      1.5        0        1    1        3
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `across` and `reduce`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   mutate(zero = across(everything(), ~ . == 0) %>% 
         reduce(`+`), non_zero = ncol(df)- zero)
      Patient1 Patient2 Patient3 zero non_zero
Gene1        0        1        2    1        2
Gene2        0        0        4    2        1
Gene3      1.5        0        1    1        2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `rowSums` only once in `within`.

```
within(df, {
  NonZero <- rowSums(df != 0)
  Zero <- ncol(df) - NonZero
  })
#       Patient1 Patient2 Patient3 Zero NonZero
# Gene1        0        1        2    1       2
# Gene2        0        0        4    2       1
# Gene3      1.5        0        1    1       2
```